# Initiate a call to multiple numbers and wait for answer

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

We want to initiate the Twilio service by calling 1 or more numbers at the same time and the first number that picks up will be used. All other numbers, if any, will be hung up on. At which point we will then connect a second number to the first number. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

Twilio Evangelist here,

There are two ways of doing this, depending on exactly what you need. The simple version if to use the [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial) and [`<Number>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/number) verbs to make 3 outbound dials, *but* this would be in response to an inbound call:

```
<Response>
  <Dial>
    <Number>+whatever</Number>
    <Number>+something</Number>
    <Number>+lastone<Number>
  </Dial>
<Response>
```

I suspect this isn't quite right for you.

The slightly more complicated version is to make 3 outbound [REST API requests to create a call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls). (You probably want to use one of the [helper libraries](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries), but I'm unsure what language you are working in.)

As soon as one of the outbound calls connects, you should use the Call SID of the other 2 outbounds (part of the response from REST API) to disconnect them. You can use the [REST API to modify live calls](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/change-call-state). Then connect the one call that answered using TwiML to dial them on the fourth number:

```
<Response>
  <Dial>
    <Number>+lastnumber</Number>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The problem that we are running into now is that we need (X) number of calls to be simultaneously rang. When we do the multiple number dial it seems that there is a delay, so the first number always rings first and the last is a few seconds behind. Is there a way to ring all numbers at the starting at the exact same time?

Comment: I believe by default you'll be rate limited to 1 outbound call per second. So you may need to talk to Twilio directly to change that. More details here: https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/twilio-basics/what-are-the-limits-on-outbound-calls-and-sms-messages-per-second Hope this helps!